# Visual Studio 2013 and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I have recently purchased a new laptop and got a new version of VS from my school. And I'm having a little trouble setting up my libraries.
I created a basic `SDL_Window`, as well as a `SDL_GLContext`.

I'm able to include my libraries and run the program, but I can't call functions like `glClearColor`, or `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`. I get a rather strage warning and an error that I have never seen before, I'm guessing it's related to the 2013 version?

I have tried ignoring all specific default libraries, as well as trying to change the programtype (Multithreaded DLL, those 4).
And I have made sure all the dll-files are in place in my system folder.

What makes me wonder is the fact that `glewInit()` works, but not `glClearColor()` etc...

Output:

> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib'
>   conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
>
> 1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Window::initOpenGL(void)" (?initOpenGL@Window@@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>C:\Users\Aleksander\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL
>   Test\Debug\OpenGL Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>            //Tested OK
#include <SDL_image.h>      //Tested OK
#include <SDL_mixer.h>      //Tested OK
#include <SDL_net.h>        //Tested OK
#include <OpenGL\glew.h>        //?
#include <freeglut\freeglut.h>  //?
#include <gl\GL.h>              //?
#include <glm\glm.hpp>      //Tested OK
#include <iostream>         //Standard OK
#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>    //Tested OK
using namespace std;


class Window {
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_GLContext context;
    bool quit;

public:
    Window();
    ~Window();

    void initSDL();
    void initOpenGL();
    void run();
};
```

Source:

```
#include "Window.h"


Window::Window() {
    printf("Starting window...\n");

    //Initialize window
    quit = false;
    initSDL();
    initOpenGL();

    //Run window
    run();
}

Window::~Window() {
    printf("Closing window...\n");

    //Clear window memory
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    //Close window library
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Window::initSDL() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) {
        quit = true;
        printf("Unable to initialize SDL!\n");
    }
    else {
        //Create window
        const char *title = "OpenGL Test";
        int pos = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;
        int w = 800;
        int h = 600;
        Uint32 flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, pos, pos, w, h, flags);

        //Create OpenGL context
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
        context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    }
}

void Window::initOpenGL() {
    GLenum init = glewInit();
    if (init != GLEW_OK) {
        quit = true;
        printf("Unable to initialize OpenGL!\n");
        printf("Error: %s!\n", glewGetErrorString(init));
    }
    else {
        //printf("Vendor: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
        //printf("Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        //printf("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    }
}

void Window::run() {
    printf("Window started running!\n");

    SDL_Event event;

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the /NODEFAULTLIB build option like it suggests?

Comment: Do you link against `opengl32.lib`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Linker > Input > Ignore All Default Libraries > Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB)

Comment: Additional dependices: I might try adding that.
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
glew32mx.lib
glew32mxs.lib

Comment: Thanks n0rd, I added "opengl32.lib" to my dependices and it worked. Amazing how easy it is to overlook things =/